# JavaScript array sort on 2 properties

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a JSON array of objects that looks something like this:

```
var garments [{
    name: 'Garment 1',
    isDesignable: false,
    priority: 3
},{
    name: 'Garment 2',
    isDesignable: false,
    priority: 1
},{
    name: 'Garment 3',
    isDesignable: true,
    priority: 3
},{
    name: 'Garment 4',
    isDesignable: true,
    priority: 2
},{
    name: 'Garment 5',
    isDesignable: true,
    priority: 4
}];
```

Initially, I needed to sort the array by **priority** so I did this:

```
garments.sort(function (a, b) {

    // By priority
    return a.priority - b.priority;
});
```

which was fine. But now, I have realised that if a garment is not designable, then it should be at the bottom of the array regardless of it's priority. Can anyone help me with the sort function so all non designable garments are at the bottom of the sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution with one line of code.

First build the difference between `isDesignable` and if the same apply the difference of `priority` as sort indicator.

```js
var garments = [{
        name: 'Garment 1',
        isDesignable: false,
        priority: 3
    }, {
        name: 'Garment 2',
        isDesignable: false,
        priority: 1
    }, {
        name: 'Garment 3',
        isDesignable: true,
        priority: 3
    }, {
        name: 'Garment 4',
        isDesignable: true,
        priority: 2
    }, {
        name: 'Garment 5',
        isDesignable: true,
        priority: 4
    }];
// sort isDesignable first and then by priority ascending
garments.sort(function (a, b) {
    return b.isDesignable - a.isDesignable || a.priority - b.priority;
});
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(garments, 0, 4) + '</pre>');

// sort reversing the former sort order by sorting, not reversing
garments.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.isDesignable - b.isDesignable || b.priority - a.priority;
});
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(garments, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 4):

```
garments.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a.isDesignable == b.isDesignable) {
        return a.priority - b.priority;
    } else if (a.isDesignable) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
});
```

Comment: Can I ask what the return 1 bit is for?

Comment: That's what the comparison function is supposed to do: return a value <0, 0 or >0 to signal that the first element is lower, equal or higher than the second. `return 1` is the case when `a` is not designable but `b` is.

Comment: I have no idea why, but this function is returning the non-designables at the front of the array and then the priorities are listed from high to low. I need it the opposite way around

Comment: Cannot reproduce this. See http://jsfiddle.net/efhrs8f1/, check your browser's console.